# Azure App Service - Node App - Do i need to createServer and required files

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a node app, that doesn't expose any port. It's just running some tasks in the background and returning some stuff onto the console that I occasionally need to look at.

I've deployed this onto Azure App Service - however it doesn't seem to run - in the logs I see
`Waiting for response to warmup request for container xxx`

I was wondering in my index.js I don't actually expose any port - namely there isn't a `const server = http.createServer()`. Is this required from Azure's side or can I disable it?

So my index.js literally looks like:

```
(async () => {
   // Check some things and do something
}
```

Also, in the https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world sample project there are the files:

- web.config
- process.json

Do I need these for the node app to run on Azure?

And finally, in teh sample node app above, it has `const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;` but where in Azure's portal is that being set? Or if its defaulting to 1337, how does Azure know that?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to run some tasks in the background, you can use [webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) instead. It is also very convenient to [check the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#ViewJobHistory).

By the way, the only ports open for Web Apps are 80 and 443. We should use `process.env.PORT` for nodejs app port. `1337` is for local test.